# Include jar to integration tests using gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, integration-testing

I want to include an external .jar in my integration tests.

It resides inside my "lib" folder, so I added the dependency for integrationTestCompile, but Eclipse complains when I use any class contained in the jar in my integration tests.

This is a sample of my build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "src/main/resources"
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "src/test/java"
        }
    }
    integrationTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/integrationTest/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/integrationTest/resources'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

task iTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath += sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //Unit test dependencies
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+' 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Integration test dependencies
    integrationTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Any thoughts on this will be appreciated.

Comment: do you have a configuration called integrationTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integrationTest` is not a standard configuration added by the java plugin. Here's what the plugin does add:

[image]

([Learn more about gradle java plugin here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html))

So, unless if you defined your own configuration called integrationTest, you should just add the integration test dependencies to `testCompile`.

Alternatively, you could add your own configuration:

```
configurations{
    integrationTest
}
```

but you will still have to add all integrationTestCompile dependencies to testCompile by doing this:

```
testCompile.extendsFrom(integrationTestCompile)
```